# Django middleware and HttpRequest change

Tags: django, httprequest, django-middleware

I have a middleware to make some calculations/check for each incoming request. Some of view need this calculations result.

As I do not want to call the same code twice, I would like to put results to HttpRequest in middleware, so view will be able to read it.

Could you help me with right hint, how can I add an object to HttpRequest?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpRequest` is a normal class, you could directly assign the object to its instance, the `request`, in the middleware. For example:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend HttpResponse by using so-called "[monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)" method. For example you can easily add or replace methods and properties into `HttpResponse` by calling following function from within your root `__init__.py` or `wsgi.py` or even `settings.py`:

```
def apply_http_request_patch():

    def get_property_value(request):
        # return lazily evaluated value

    from django.http import HttpRequest
    HttpRequest.some_property = property(get_property_value)
```